# woocommerce added_to_cart event doesn't get triggered

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have installed Menu Cart Pro for a shop (genesis child theme). It drops down the cart on hover as per plugin functionality. However, I also need it to dropdown on "Add to Cart" button click. The plugin developer asked me to add this code to the functions.php. I did but it doesn't work. I get 400 Bad Request for admin-ajax.php
I changed event to on click and I can have the cart dropdow but before the item is added to cart. I need the updated cart to be shown.

here's the suggested code:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wpo_menucart_animate_flyout' );
function wpo_menucart_animate_flyout() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function( $ ) {
                    $( document.body ).on( 'added_to_cart', function() {
                        alert("on added to cart");
                    $('.sub-menu.wpmenucart').fadeIn(400, function() {
                            $(this).delay(3000).fadeOut(400);
                    });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

I searched other similar questions and most of them have the same code suggested. I am unable to figure why my code doesn't work and why I'm getting 400 for admin-ajax.php.
A friend suggested I add the code to a JS file and localize the script. That didn't work either. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I know there is too late, but I've solved this problem and didn't saw an  answer here. Just for helping all guys like me, there is my solve method.

Be sure that your jQuery is registered before woocommerce scripts.

That's all :D

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).